# Как работать с отдельным уровнем, в многоуровневым меню вложенности? redbean

Tags: php, orm, redbeanphp

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как работаь с отдельным уровнем?

```
$razdel = R::findAll( 'bbrazdel' );
$arrays = R::exportAll( $razdel );
echo '<pre>';print_r($arrays);echo '</pre>';
```

Накидал такой код для отображения. Оно сначала выводит правильно, а потом рекурсия продолжается, и не пойму как её обрабатывать.

Comment: По данному коду ничего не понятно, здесь нет рекурсии, и выводит один раз ищите выше в своем коде, здесь его нет

Comment: Просто ответ очень большой, не хотел его вставлять. Не то что он зацикливается. А выводит дерево вложености (правильно). И потом дальше продолжает создавать деревья, уже следующих уровней в отдельные массивы, и они получаются на одном уровне с родителями.

Comment: Так при чем тут редбин, это орм для работы с базой, вывод уже осуществляется вами, руками или фреймворком.